# How to make angular submit fire only once?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently trying to submit a form. However, I am allowed to login only after clicking the submit button twice. I would like to know how to fix this please

Login page.html

```
<div class="central-form">
    <form class="login-form" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="checkLogin()" autocomplete="disabled">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" formControlName="email" autocomplete="new-email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf = "triedLogin == true && approvedLogin == false">
                <span class="error">Invalid E-mail or Password</span>
            </div>
            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Login component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../authentication.service';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SignInData } from '../Model/signinData';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login-page',
    templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login-page.component.css']
})

export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {
    approvedLogin:boolean = false;
    triedLogin: boolean = false;

    loginForm = new FormGroup({
        email : new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required])),
        password : new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(8), Validators.required]))
    });
    
    constructor(
        private authentication: AuthenticationService, 
        private route: Router
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.authentication.logout();
    }

    checkLogin()
    {
        this.triedLogin = true;
        this.approvedLogin = this.getLoginResult();
        if (this.approvedLogin)
        {
            this.route.navigate(['details']);
        }
    }
    
    private getLoginResult(): boolean
    {
        var signindata = new SignInData(this.loginForm.value.email, this.loginForm.value.password);
        return this.authentication.authenticate(signindata);
    }
}
```

Authentication service, where I retrieve user details and checks for valid login credentials

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SignInData } from './Model/signinData';
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthenticationService {
    isAuthenticated: boolean = false;
    employee:any;
    private logins: any = [];

    constructor(private router: Router, private service: SharedService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getLogins();
        console.log(this.logins);
    }

    private getLogins()
    {
        this.service.getLoginDetails().subscribe(data =>
            Object.assign(this.logins, data)
        )
    }

    authenticate(signinData: SignInData): boolean
    {
        return this.checkCredentials(signinData);
    }

    private checkCredentials(signinData: SignInData): boolean
    {
        this.getLogins();
        var found = false;
        //Loop through each element to check for user login is correct
        this.logins.forEach(element => {
            console.log(this.logins);
            if (found == false)
            {
                if (element.email == signinData.getEmail())
                {
                    if (element.password == signinData.getPassword())
                    {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return found;
    }

    logout()
    {
        this.isAuthenticated = false;
        this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
}
```

Shared services, where I am retrieving data from my RestAPI

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {

    readonly APIUrl = "https://localhost:*****/api/";

    constructor(private http:HttpClient) 
    { }

    getLoginDetails():Observable<any[]>
    {
        return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl+"Login/");
    }
}
```

Comment: you have async code here this.authentication.authenticate(signindata). You need to wait for this request to ends before check this.approvedLogin

Answer (score 1):

Hope I know what happens,
into service you call `ngOnInit()`, but Angular Service don't have that live hooks, btw you should be implements they.
Thats mean on first click you dont have `AuthenticationService.logins`, then when you call `checkCredentials()`, `AuthenticationService.logins is undefined`, and you get your error.

How to solve it? Easiest way - copy into constructor

```
 constructor(private router: Router, private service: SharedService) { 
     this.getLogins();
     console.log(this.logins);
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I have checked the getLogins function, I have tried to display the values before any execution, and it does show all my values, but for any unknown reason I am getting that error

Answer (score 0):

Hi for double click you cannot use ngSubmit event binding on form.use dblclick event on button and capture that.

```
<div class="central-form">
    <form class="login-form" [formGroup]="loginForm" autocomplete="disabled">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" formControlName="email" autocomplete="new-email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf = "triedLogin == true && approvedLogin == false">
                <span class="error">Invalid E-mail or Password</span>
            </div>
            
            <button type="submit" (dblclick)="checkLogin()" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, the problem is not that I want to double click on the button. The problem is that when I click submit on the first time, the login fails even with correct email and password. However, when I click login on second time, then login is approved. This is the error I want to fix.

Comment: Oh I see. I think if you convert your function getLogins to promise and await it in checkCredential then it should work